# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::save does not exist

Tags: laravel

I want to store a file in database with User uploader and group name and documentname and description

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'documentname' => 'required',
                'documentname.*' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip,png,jpge,jpg'
        ]);
        if($request->hasfile('documentname'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('documentname') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->move(base_path() . '/storage/app/public', $name);
                $data[] = $name;
            }
         }


        //  $file= new File();
        $data = new Country();

        $file = $request->file;
        $file->documentname=json_encode($data);
        $data->uploadername=$request->uploadername;
        $data->groupname=$request->groupname;
        $data->description=$request->description;

        $file->save();


        return back()->with('message', 'Your files has been send successfully');
    }
```

i already research to fix but i dont know where

Comment: Instead of: `$file->save();` use: `$data->save();` I guess this is simply caused by a **typo**.

Answer (score 0):

okay, the way to go about this is to use `$data->save();` since you initialized `$data` as an object of the `Country` class.

Comment: already answer is posted in comments